# Rails Twitter config global

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, devise, global-variables

I am using [Twitter Gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) from sferik and [Devise Gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) from plataformatec.

If I understand well the process, here is how I do it : When the user sign in with his Twitter account, I store his token and token_secret in database so I can do :

```
@client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key    = "MY_KEY"
  config.consumer_secret = "MY_SECRET"
  config.access_token        = current_user.token
  config.access_token_secret = current_user.token_secret
end
```

So every user have a different `config.access_token(_secret)` for `@client`.

My question is what is the best way to make the Twitter client available globally in every controller **but only when the user is logged in** ?

I cannot put it in `config/initializers` because `config.access_token(_secret)` is not yet set...

Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple in fact...

Just added a before_action in my ApplicationController and check if a user is logged in or not.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_twitter_client

  private

  def set_twitter_client
    if user_signed_in?
      @client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
        config.consumer_key    = "MY_KEY"
        config.consumer_secret = "MY_SECRET"
        config.access_token        = current_user.token
        config.access_token_secret = current_user.token_secret
      end
    end
  end

end
```